# SMS for messaging between applications

Tags: messaging, sms

What would be the issues or advantages to using SMS messaging for inter-application messaging? more or less reliable than http? etc.

Comment: [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: SMS as in the text messages in phones? Or is there a new protocol by the same name?

Comment: What problem are you looking to solve by using this very unconventional idea?

Answer (score 2):

- HTTP is time-tested for inter-process communication, it's recilient, etc.
- SMS are subject to carrier fees, carries arrangement, international inter-carrier agreement
- There's usually more latency in SMS
- Many SMS never get delivered or get delivered late
- HTTP is based on TCP/IP, the foundation on which modern internet communication relies.
- SMS in intrinsically less secure for corporative communication and additional infraesctructure must be provided to provide enterprise class security.
- SMS could potentially have more international boundaries than HTTP.
- As mentioned by @jörg-w-mittag, SMS is ~100000 times more expensive than HTTP.

On the bright side I'd say that in areas where there's no data coverage, a SMS based message queue could be an option.

Comment: At least on my plan, SMS are ~100000 times more expensive than HTTP: 0,09€/160 Byte vs. 7€/1GiByte. Actually, that's just for highspeed data. If I were content with 64kBit/s, HTTP would be free.